# How to configure PFN in DMClient CSP

Tags: java

I want to configure PFN name in the DMClient CSP , how can i do it ? is it from CSP form or OMA-DM protocol ? please help with this

Answer (score 0):

Need to send PFN name in the WAP provisioning XML in the RST response message.